# VBA Webscrape: Referencing a pop-up webpage tab

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping, tabs

I've done a decent amount of scouring over the internet to find the answer to my question although it has been to no avail. I'm fairly new to VBA Webscraping so I apologize if my question is fairly straightforward. That being said, let me explain:

I am currently trying to webscrape information from an internal website for my company. Using HTML id's and class names I was able to reference the needed search bar. Although, once the script clicks the search button on the webpage, a new tab is opened. Thereafter, the rest of my script continues to reference the original tab rather than the new tab that the information I need is derived from.

I have tried to use innerText to see if I could pull the url directly from the HTML although it doesn't seem it is located in the HTML. Additionally, I cannot create another "ie" to direct to the new url because the url for the new tab is dynamic and based off your search. Therefore, the only possibility I assume I have left is switching tabs and I was unable to find any information on how to do that.

If anyone can solve this dilemma, I know it'll be the coding gods of StackOverflow.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Atlas_Search()

    Dim SearchString As String
    SearchString = Range("A1")

    Dim ie As Object
    Dim ie2 As Object
    Dim form As Object
    Dim form2 As Object
    Dim form3 As Object
    Dim button As Variant
    Dim var1 As Object

    Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium
    With ie
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate 
    "www.google.com"
    With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows
    Set ie = .Item(.Count - 1)
    End With
    End With


   ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")(10).Value = SearchString
   Set form = ie.document.getelementbyid("MainContent_btnSearchFullText")
   form.Click
   Set form2 = 
   ie.document.getelementbyid("MainContent_rptrSearchResults_lnkApplicationid_0")
   form2.Click
   Set form3 = ie2.document.getelementsbyclassname("nav2link")(9)
   form3.Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried `Shell.Application.Windows` and checking the URL to find the window you're looking for?  That seems safer than assuming a fixed index.

Comment: Meant to type "Have you tried *looping over* Shell.Application.Windows and checking the URL"

Answer (score 0):

Each tab opened within IE window is created in a separate brand new IE instance, but since all that tabs belong to the only IE window, they have the same HWND as the window.

So you can count the number of the tabs in the IE window within a loop conditionally, increasing a counter only for windows whose HWND matches the target.

Count such way the number of windows prior initiate new tab opening. Then open new tab, and wait until the number of the windows increases by one, that means that the tab is created. After that the last one IE instance counted in the loop is the new tab actually. You may add extra check for location.

That is failproof and reliable way to fetch the new tab IE instance, even if there are a bunch of another HWND explorer windows are being opened at the moment. Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42308848/2165759) which shows the approach.